# Unexpected Type while compiling

Tags: java, types, compilation, int

I wrote the following piece of code in JAVA:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equations
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println ("This program solves a system of 2 linear  equations" +"\n"+
        "Enter the coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2:");

            int a11 = scan.nextInt();
            int a12 = scan.nextInt();
            int a21 = scan.nextInt();
            int a22 = scan.nextInt();
            int b1 = scan.nextInt();
            int b2 = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println ("Eq: " + a11 + "*x1" + "+" + a12 + "*x2 = " + b1);
            System.out.println ("Eq: " + a21 + "*x1" + "+" + a22 + "*x2 = " + b2);

            if(((a11*a22)-(a12*a21)) != 0){
                double Equ1single = ((b1*a22)-(b2*a12))/((a11*a22)-(a12*a21));
                double Equ2single = ((b2*a11)-(b1*a21))/((a11*a22)-(a12*a21));
                System.out.println ("Single solution: (" + Equ1single + "," + Equ2single + ")");
            } 

            if(((b2*a11)-(b1*a21)) = 0){
                System.out.println ("Many solutions");
            }

       }
}
```

I get an error while compiling this code in BlueJay environment.
The error is as follows:

> unexpected type. required variable;found value.

it marks "-(b1*a21)" as the problem. but yet i did declare a21 as an int. And also, the "if" condition before is "identical" and does not give any error.

What is the problem with compiling this?

Comment: try with 2 `=` e.g. `if(((b2*a11)-(b1*a21)) == 0){`

Comment: `=` is assignment and `==` for comparison.

Comment: You habe to use == instead of =. == is the test for equality, = assigns the result of the expression in the right-hand sie to the variable on the left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(((b2*a11)-(b1*a21)) = 0){
```

should instead be

```
if(((b2*a11)-(b1*a21)) == 0){
```

Comment: Please just answer this in  a comment and vote to close as typo.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm not sure I see why?  It's a valid question, with a valid answer.  It might be a duplicate, but it's not an invalid question, I think?

Comment: It's a question that was caused by a typo. It seems obvious to me they meant to use `==`. I don't want us to encourage these questions, nor answering them. IMO. (I'm out of votes right now, otherwise I would've voted to close the question.)